# Python write a list to a text file

Tags: string, list

I am using python `format` method to write a list of numbers into a text file. When the list length is fixed I can do:

```
a = [16,1,16,1]
myfile.write('{0},{1},{2},{3}'.format(*a) + "\n")
```

My question is how to use the format method when the size of list is not fixed. Is there any easy easy way of doing this? Rather than first create a string `b`, and then map `a` to `b`. I am not sure if I can use something like `myfile.write('{all elements in a}'.format(*a) + "\n")`

```
b=''
for i in range(len(a)):
    if i<(len(a)-1):
        b=b+'{'+ str(i) + '},'
    else:
        b=b+'{'+ str(i) + '}'

myfile.write(b.format(*a) + "\n")
```

Comment: why are you writing a list to a text file? Curious, because if it is to use in a Python program later, this deserves a different answer.

Comment: I am using Python to create a text input file for an old FORTRAN program. The inputs come from a web GUI.

Comment: o ok. I was going to say use `pickle` but that is not what you are using it for, so carry on =).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str.join`:

```
>>> lis = [16,1,16,1]
>>> ','.join(str(x) for x in lis) + '\n'
'16,1,16,1\n'
>>> lis = range(10)
>>> ','.join(str(x) for x in lis) + '\n'
'0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\n'
```

Comment: Thanks! So it seems like no easy way to use `format` method? I just want my code looks consistent...

Comment: @tao.hong `str.join` is the preferred way to do this.